# How to make a partially editable tree model in Qt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt4

I want to change the editable tree view example that qt provides so that the first column is not editable, while the next one is.

Here is the repo:
https://github.com/pyqt/examples/tree/master/itemviews/editabletreemodel

I know it has something to do with the flags. In `editabletreemodel.py` they have a class `TreeModel`.

```
    def flags(self, index):

        
        if not index.isValid():
            return 0

        return Qt.ItemIsEditable | super(TreeModel, self).flags(index)
```

I can change from Qt.ItemIsEditable to Qt.ItemIsSelectable, and this would make all fields uneditable. But this is not what I want

Basically I want to make the `Title` column selectable and the `Description` column editable, how can I get this behavior?
[image]

Comment: Please remember that questions should normally be self-contained (remember: a question should not only help you, but anybody looking for a similar issue anytime in the future): it's possible that at some point the maintainer of the repository will remove it, especially considering that the linked repository is *not* the official one (PyQt is not on GitHub). For future reference, consider providing a [mre]: in your case, it would not be necessary to use the custom model in the example, as a basic QStandardItemModel would suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check for the index column in the `flags()` implementation and then remove the `ItemIsEditable` flag using the exclusive binary operator:

```
def flags(self, index):
    flags = super(TreeModel, self).flags(index)
    if index.column() == 0:
        flags &= ~Qt.ItemIsEditable
    return flags
```

This is assuming that you're using a super class that always provides editable items, otherwise just add the flag (the default QAbstractItemModel returns only selectable and enabled items):

```
def flags(self, index):
    flags = super(TreeModel, self).flags(index)
    if index.column() > 0:
        flags |= Qt.ItemIsEditable
    return flags
```

Comment: Yes, the second snipped worked form me, as the example uses a QAbstractItemModel. However I cant find the default flag for QAbstratItemModel as Selectable in the documentation https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html . Where can I find this type of information?

Comment: @JoãoRamiro It's right in the [`flags`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#flags) documentation: "The base class implementation returns a combination of flags that enables the item (ItemIsEnabled) and allows it to be selected (ItemIsSelectable)."